# Validating JSON messages against Swagger definition in .Net core

Tags: c#, validation, swagger, jsonschema, openapi.net

I created a REST API using a Swagger definition, now I need to validate incoming messages using that swagger schema. I found several solutions but not in .net
Is There any library in .net that can do it?
(like swagger-schema-validator in java)

Comment: There is a list of implementations for different use cases in the JSON schema page:
https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-dotnet